# Terraform - create s3 bucket from list in different regions

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, region

I have the following terraform module that creates s3buckets from list. I have resource aws_s3_bucket in another path and it works.

s3test/main.tf

```
module "s3-client-transfer" {
  for_each = toset(var.buckets)
  source   = "../s3resource"

  bucket = each.value
}
```

s3test/terraform.auto.tfvars

```
region = eu-west-1
buckets = [
  "bucket1",
  "bucket2"
]
```

s3test/variables.tf

```
variable "region" {
  description = "AWS Region"
}

variable "buckets" {

  default = []
}
```

s3resource/s3.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket        = local.bucket_name
  acl           = "private"
  force_destroy = true
}
```

s3resource/main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "< 4.0.0"
    }
  }
}

locals {
  bucket      = var.bucket
  bucket_name = "prefix-${var.bucket}"
```

s3resource/variables.tf

```
variable "bucket" {
  description = "The name of the bucket"
}
```

This is ok if I create bucket1 and bucket2 in region eu-west-1, but I'd like to add a new bucket to list but in different region. For example bucket3 and bucket4 in us-east-1
I was trying to use multiple providers or create new list.

This is my solution with list but it doesn't work:

s3test/terraform.auto.tfvars

```
region = "eu-west-1"

s3_buckets = {
  "euwest1buckets" = {
    region_name  = "eu-west-1"
    bucket_names = ["bucket1", "bucket2"]
  }
  "useast1bucket" = {
    region_name  = "us-east-1"
    bucket_names = ["bucket3", "bucket4"]
  }
}
```

s3test/main.tf

```
module "s3-client-transfer" {
  for_each = var.s3buckets
  source = "../s3resource"
  region = each.value.regionname
  bucket_names = each.value.bucketnames
}
```

s3test/variables.tf

```
variable "region" {
  type = string
}

variable "s3_buckets" {
  type = map(object({
    region_name  = string
    bucket_names = list(string)
  }))
}
```

s3resource/s3.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  for_each = var.s3buckets

  bucket = each.value.bucketnames
  acl    = "private"
  region = each.value.regionname
}
```

I got following errors:

```
 Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 1, in module "s3-client-transfer":
│    1: module "s3-client-transfer" {
│ 
│ The argument "bucket_name" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 5, in module "s3-client-transfer":
│    5:   bucket_names = each.value.bucketnames
│ 
│ An argument named "bucket_names" is not expected here. Did you mean "bucket_name"?
```

How can I fix it? What's the best practise? Should I try again with multiple providers?

Comment: I think you want `each.value.bucket_names` and `each.value.region_name`. Also, your variable in the child module is called `s3_buckets` and you are trying to pass the child module a variable called `bucket_names`. Additionally, the S3 bucket resource is using also a non-existent variable `for_each = var.s3buckets`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also face a known issue with terraform related to it's inability to work with dynamic providers, see more details here

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19932

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25244